# Unity: Player Animations Won't Work

Tags: animation, unity-game-engine, unityscript

I have recently followed [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FRMy5B3dD_I) for my Player animations but my player is constantly in a jumping state. I've been trying to troubleshoot this for the past few days and I now know that the player walk animations works perfectly, it's just the jump. I've check the scripts and they all seem the be correct but the ground variable in the animator is always set to true. Can anybody help?

Comment: Sharing some code (your version) may help us help you a little better.

Comment: It's too big to put it here. Is it alright if I PM it to you?

Comment: I don't have a huge amount of time, but sharing jumping relevant code should help. I don't know what others think, but I'd use pastebin worst case scenario.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/X2bBhTcU

Comment: Thanks the code for the player, by the way.

Comment: The code is contradicting to their own methods. In your FixUpdate() You're always setting the anim.SetBool("Ground", true); to TRUE so it will always be true because in every fix frame. it is called.

Comment: Now the jumping animation won't play at all.

Comment: In the fixedUpdate function try changing the line to:
anim.SetBool("Ground", grounded);

Comment: Now the player is constantly playing the jumping animation again

Comment: Never mind, I accidentally set the transition conditions for jumping to true instead of false.